# Negative Variables in LESS

Tags: css, less

New to LESS, I am attempting to center a div using the following:

```
#form_block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    @width: 800px;
    @height: 500px;
    width: @width;
    height: @height;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -@width/2 px;
    margin-top: -250px;
```

It seems like `margin-top` is set correctly since it the dimensions are explicitly there. But I can't seem to take the negative of a variable no matter how hard I try (ie. -(@width), -1 * @width, etc) Any ideas? It may just be a silly mistake.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue earlier today (with lessphp). Try:

```
margin-left: -(@width/2);
```

(without `px`)

And you should also round the value:

```
margin-left: -(round(@width/2));
```